# Android: how to save ArrayList items even if app shutdown?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, arraylist

I am developing an app in which i have to show all the installed Applications in a listview with checkboxes.Whenever the user selects any checkbox from the list that Application Info object (corresponding to checked checkbox) is added to my global class variable (ArrayList added_apps). I am succeed in doing so. but the problem is that whenever i exits the app all of the items that the user added to added_apps ArrayList are not saved. I have to again add the items in arraylist to proceed further. I have tried so far and here is my code but it does not work.

Code for displaying Installed Application and added to Global class variable added_apps ArrayList on checkboxClick Listener:

mainactivity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.pc.fkidshell.Teen3Activity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Add Selected Apps"
        android:width="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_app"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activitymain.java:

```
public class Teen3Activity extends ListActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teen3);
        //teenadd=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.teenaddtb);
        //setSupportActionBar(teenadd);
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Restrict Your APP's");
        Button btn1=(Button)  findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MyAddedapss.writeList(Teen3Activity.this,MyAddedapss.getAdded_apps()); //here i am storing ArrayList of Added applications to file
                if(MyAddedapss.getAdded_apps().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to ADD!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Apps Added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Teen3Activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Teen3Activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list)
    {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName))
                {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }



    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(Teen3Activity.this, R.layout.row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Teen3Activity.this, null, "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Application Adapter:

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ApplicationInfo> appsList)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) {
            checkList.add(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_app);
            checkBox.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position)); // set the tag so we can identify the correct row in the listener
            checkBox.setChecked(checkList.get(position));// set the status as we stored it
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener); // set the listener

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
        }
        return view;
    }
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            checkList.set((Integer)buttonView.getTag(),isChecked); // get the tag so we know the row and store the status
            if(isChecked)
            {
                int addapppos = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                ApplicationInfo p=appsList.get(addapppos);
                MyAddedapss.setAdded_apps(p);
                buttonView.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

MyAddedApps.java: (Global class that contain write method to save arraylist to file)

```
public class MyAddedapss extends Application {
    private static ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> added_apps=new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();

    public static void setAdded_apps(ApplicationInfo element)
    {
        added_apps.add(element);
    }
    public static ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> getAdded_apps(){

        return added_apps;
    }
    public static boolean remove_app(ApplicationInfo element)
    {
        return added_apps.remove(element);
    }

    public static ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> readList(Context c)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = c.openFileInput("NAME");
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> list = (ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>)is.readObject();
            is.close();
            return list;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void writeList(Context c, ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> list){
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(list);
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I missed it but I don't see you calling readList anywhere. Are you actually loading the list?

Comment: yes I do but i use readlist method in another acticvity where i have to load that added apps list and then performing other operations on that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to convert you list of objects to a JSON string. After you can save this string in a Shared Preferences. When you app wake up, you can retrieve the list from Shared Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

One way of storing values permanently in your application is to use SharedPreferences. Basically the only thing you need to do is to store your values in SharedPreferences upon check, and delete them on uncheck.

Read more at:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html